# Execute decode function stored in bytea column

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.6

I have a bytea column in a table that contains a function decode(). What I have done to get the actual data is as follows:

```
select filename, convert_from(data,'UTF-8') from attachments limit 20; //this returns me decode function
select decode(E'...','hex'); // I am executing the above returned function
```

The above is fine as long as I have to select one row. But now my requirement is to get more than one result. How can I get the result in single query? I have tried using pl/pgsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_data(integer, _type anyelement, OUT _result anyelement)
  AS
$x$
BEGIN

EXECUTE
'SELECT ' || (select convert_from(data,'UTF-8') as data from attachments limit $1)
INTO _result;

END;
$x$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But this works only for single row and single column. What I want is a single query to fetch 2 columns without using pl/pgsql if possible. I am using this query from my Java based web app.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing there. Are you saying `convert_from(data,'UTF-8')` returns the source code of a function, then you then want to apply to something else?

Comment: Yes convert_from(data,'UTF-8') returns me source code of a function decode() which I execute again with select statement to get the actual data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need procedural code for this, since there is no provision for dynamic statements in SQL.

The following function converts all attachments:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getemall(
   IN v_type anyelement,
   OUT v_result anyelement
) RETURNS SETOF anyelement
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$DECLARE
   v_stmt text;
BEGIN
   FOR v_stmt IN
      SELECT convert_from(data,'UTF-8')
      FROM attachments
   LOOP
      EXECUTE v_stmt INTO v_result;
      RETURN NEXT;
   END LOOP;
END;$$;
```

Comment: I have modified the loop as `FOR v_type IN
      SELECT convert_from(data,'UTF-8'), filename
      FROM attachments
   LIMIT 2
   LOOP
      raise notice 'value: %', v_type;
      EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || v_type INTO v_result;
      RETURN NEXT;
   END LOOP;`. But it still returns me only one column. How do I fetch 2 columns?

Comment: Add a second `OUT` parameter to the function and add the parameter to the `INTO` clause of the `EXECUTE` statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have written the function with few changes

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getmeall(tName text, fNameCol text, dataCol text,fSize 
numeric) 
 RETURNS TABLE(bdata bytea, fname text) LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
 $$DECLARE
  v_stmt text;
  v_name text;

 BEGIN
  FOR v_stmt,v_name IN
   EXECUTE format('SELECT encode(%s, ''escape''), %s FROM   %s
    WHERE  $1 IS NOT NULL AND $2 IS NOT NULL LIMIT $3'
    , dataCol, fNameCol, tName)
    USING  dataCol, fNameCol, fSize
  LOOP
    fname:=v_name;
    IF strpos(v_stmt,'decode') = 1 THEN
        EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || v_stmt INTO bdata;
    ELSE
        bdata:=v_stmt;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEXT;
  END LOOP;
END;$$;
```

And finally calling it this way.

`select * from getmeall('attachments', '"filename"', '"data"',2)`